# Adding rules efficiently

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In background.js I am using rules but I am also using regex so many times. I have declarativeContent.ShowPageAction based on these rules.

```
new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({pageUrl: { urlMatches: 'https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*microsoft.com'},}),
new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({pageUrl: { urlMatches: 'https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*google.com'},}),
new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({pageUrl: { urlMatches: 'https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*amazon.com'},}),
```

Is there a way to use regex only once and use it as in javascript

```
myRegexInstance.test(collectionOfURLs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regexp. They're slow and you're duplicating the job already performed by the API: it already separated the URL into parts which you can test separately.

Use `hostSuffix`:

```js
[
  '.microsoft.com',
  '.google.com',
  '.amazon.com',
].map(s => new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({pageUrl: {hostSuffix: s}}))
```

The leading dot will match both `*://google.com/` and any subdomain e.g. `*://www.google.com/`